# Can selenium be used for free in corporations for commercial projects

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am part of a team which has been handled the responsibilty of setting up UI automation for our project. I just wanted to know if selenium webdriver (the one that you download from : https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) can be used for free in commercial projects?

PS : We are planning to use open JDK for the implementation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's under the Apache 2.0 license: https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0  Different drivers may have different licenses but they are similar.  The one exception might be Microsoft's that I believe you can use, but not distribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/microsoft-edge/microsoft-edge-devtools-license-terms  I think geckodriver is CDDL: https://opensource.org/licenses/CDDL-1.0  What this means as far as distribution (non-microsoft stuff) is that, I believe, you need to open source the code that uses the Selenium bindings and webdrivers.

Comment: Yes, you can use that for commercial projects, it's completely free and opensrouce tool, that's why most of the companies using Selenium.